# How to save an empty datefield in django

Tags: django, forms

I have an optional datefield in my form, when I save it and it's empty I got the validation error about the invalid format.
In my model, I wrote `blank=True` and `null=True`.

Model :

```
created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
```

Form :

```
class XxxForm(forms.ModelForm):

    created=forms.DateField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Xxx
```

Error :

> u"" value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM format

**Update** :
I found the solution which is :

```
created = request.POST['created']
        if not created:
                created = None
```

It works that way ! thanks everyone

Comment: Can you show the form code? The full model? The **exact** error that you get?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `DateTimeField` in the form, not a `DateField`.

[EDIT]
Also try to drop `created=forms.DateField(required=False)` from your form declaration. It is not needed there since you have it in the model already.

Comment: What version of django are you running?